# how to use bootstrap.min.js in react 4 application

Tags: reactjs

I want to use bootstrap 4 in my react redux application. Some bootstrap component is not working properly like - Modal, SelectBox, etc.

What is the best approach or best practice to create a reusable bootstrap component - Like modal.

Comment: Refer [Here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121) and [Here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: I don't want to add any react library. Please tell me how to create own bootstrap based react component like modal.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I import bootstrap4 by doing this:

1. run `npm install bootstrap popper.js jquery`
2. copy `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">`
    to index.html `<header>`
3. in any react component file, type `require('bootstrap')`

then you can do any custom component from boostrap

Answer (score 0):

Instead of traditionally downloading bootstrap and linking it to your react-app, just include it to your app thru npm and add it to your dependencies

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap --save
```

Complete installation guide [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/).

Then you can now import any component you want.

For more bootstrap components, refer [Here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts)

React-bootstrap works well on react apps better than the generic bootstrap library because it is made specifically for react apps.

Comment: I don't want to add any react library. Please tell me how to create own bootstrap based react component like modal.